# Sending Form via AJAX in plain javascript (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have the following Form which I would like to send via an AJAX request.  I am unsure how to proceed in the line 'xmlhttp.open'.  I am trying to upload a video file to a third party video hosting site (using their API)and they have provided me with a URL ('upload_link_secure')to upload the file to.  Please can someone advise?

my HTML:

```
<form id="upload" action="'+upload_link_secure+'" method="PUT" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" id="vidInput">
  <button type="submit" id="submitFile" onclick="uploadMyVid(\''+upload_link_secure+'\')">Upload Video</button>
</form>
```

my javascript:

```
 var uploadMyVid = function(upload_link_secure){

        var form = document.getElementById('upload')

        // FETCH FILEIST OBJECTS
        var vidFile = document.getElementById('vidInput').files;

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest;

        xmlhttp.open('PUT', );  // NOT SURE HOW TO COMPLETE THIS LINE???
        xmlhttp.send(vidFile);

    }
```

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than just sending a complete fileList, but basically the arguments are `.open(method, url)` so you have to add the URL to upload to.

Comment: i think you can complete it based on documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open

Comment: i'm a little confused with the 'action' attribute in the Form element.  My thoughts are this element would send the file to the url.  Would i still need to duplicate this request at the xmlhttp.open line...

Comment: if you make sync request you don't need to specify action url, but in your case, you did async request, so XHR don't know anything about your endpoint, yes you need to set it explicitly

Comment: Are you trying to send the files using `<form>` or `XMLHttpRequest()`?

Comment: trying to send  using XMLHttpRequest()

Comment: What is purpose of using `PUT` instead of `POST`?

Comment: I am using an API and I am instructed to use PUT

Comment: Use the provided URL.

Answer (score 5):

First of all your `action` attribute not correct, change to some endpoint like `/upload` for example.

Here is a simple example without server side.

```js
var form = document.getElementById("upload-form"),
        actionPath = "";
        formData = null;

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        formData = new FormData(form);
        actionPath = form.getAttribute("action");

        xhr.open("POST", actionPath);
        xhr.send(formData);

    }, false);
```

```html
<form id="upload-form" action="/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" id="file">
      <button type="submit">Upload Video</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This solution will work, but you'll need to define the xhr variable first.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute `<span>` element for `<button>` element, use `click` event handler attached to `#submitFile` element; `FormData()` at `XMLHttpRequest()` to send `File` object within `<input type="file">` `.files` object; remove `action` attribute at `<form>` element, set `URL` of `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open()` to `URL` provided for `PUT` request

```
<body>
  <form id="upload">
    <input type="file" id="vidInput">
    <span id="submitFile" 
      style="-webkit-appearance:button;-moz-appearance:button;padding:4px;font-family:arial;font-size:12px">Upload Video</span>
  </form>
  <script>
    function uploadMyVid(event) {

      // FETCH FILEIST OBJECTS
      var vidFile = document.getElementById('vidInput').files;

      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest;

      xmlhttp.open('PUT', "upload_link_secure");

      var data = new FormData();
      data.append("file", vidFile[0], vidFile[0].name);

      xmlhttp.send(data);

    }

    var button = document.getElementById("submitFile");
    button.addEventListener("click", uploadMyVid);
  </script>
</body>
```